# Optimizing for loop in big data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, bigdata

I have a large data frame (6 million rows) with one row for entry times and next one for exit times of the same unit (id). I need to put them together.

Original data looks something like the following (please bear in mind that some "id" may entry and exit twice like in case of id=1):

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='id   time
1  "15/12/2014 06:30"
1   "15/12/2014 06:31"
1 "15/12/2014 06:34"
1 "15/12/2014 06:35"
2  "15/12/2014 06:36"
2  "15/12/2014 06:37"
3 "15/12/2014 06:38"
3 "15/12/2014 06:39"')
```

Output that I need:

```
id  entry   exit
1   15/12/2014 06:30    15/12/2014 06:31
2   15/12/2014 06:34    15/12/2014 06:35
3   15/12/2014 06:36    15/12/2014 06:37
4   15/12/2014 06:38    15/12/2014 06:39
```

Right now I tried a for loop which picks the id and entry time from row 1 and the exit time from time from row2, and puts them together:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
outputdf[i,1] <- df[i+i-1,1]
outputdf[i,2] <- df[i+i-1,2]
outputdf[i,3] <- df[i+i-1+1,2]
}
```

The problem is that it is very inefficient (works for 10k subsets but not for my 6million data frame). I need something that takes less than a minute at least. I have 6 million rows in the `df`. Do you know any alternative faster than this loop to match rows?

Comment: Code optimization questions should be asked on CodeReview rather than StackOverflow http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
  library(data.table)
  dcast.data.table(setDT(df)[ ,c('.id', 'Seq'):= 
        list(c('entry', 'exit'), gl(.N,2, .N))], id+Seq~.id, value.var='time')

  #   id Seq            entry             exit
  #1:  1   1 15/12/2014 06:30 15/12/2014 06:31
  #2:  1   2 15/12/2014 06:34 15/12/2014 06:35
  #3:  2   3 15/12/2014 06:36 15/12/2014 06:37
  #4:  3   4 15/12/2014 06:38 15/12/2014 06:39
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), time = 
   structure(1:8, .Label = c("15/12/2014 06:30", 
 "15/12/2014 06:31", "15/12/2014 06:34", "15/12/2014 06:35", "15/12/2014 06:36", 
 "15/12/2014 06:37", "15/12/2014 06:38", "15/12/2014 06:39"), class
   = "factor")),.Names = c("id", "time"), class = "data.frame", row.names
  = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @akrun, I think that I missed an important point in my question, that some "id" may have enter and exit twice, so entry, exit, entry, exit. Therefore, I will have 4 rows in the original df with the same id number. If I dcast, I will end up with the 4 records per id, but I need a single record for each entry-exit pair. As an analogy, think of air passengers. Usually you may check in and check out at the destination airport, but some passengers may check in, check out at destination and take another flight in the same day. I would need a row for each flight.

Comment: The dataset has a row for passenger entry and another one for passenger exit. Some passengers (most of them), travel several times a day, so entering the network, exiting, and entering and exiting again later on. There is an ID for every passenger but there are many passenger travelling at the same time too. Sorry if it sounds messy

Comment: there is a follow up question, as I need to move more columns, I am a bit stack trying to get it down with your code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564299/r-dcast-efficiently-large-datasets-with-multiple-variables

Comment: @user3507584  I will check that one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but how about this??

```
indx   <- seq(1,nrow(df)-1,2)
result <- with(df,data.frame(seq=seq(indx),id=id[indx],entry=time[indx],exit=time[indx+1]))
result
#   seq id            entry             exit
# 1   1  1 15/12/2014 06:30 15/12/2014 06:31
# 2   2  1 15/12/2014 06:34 15/12/2014 06:35
# 3   3  2 15/12/2014 06:36 15/12/2014 06:37
# 4   4  3 15/12/2014 06:38 15/12/2014 06:39
```

Comment: I am trying this solution but I get `Error in id[indx] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. And I get it for `time[indx]` too. Do you know why?

Comment: Is your data in a data frame called `df` and does `df` have columns `time` and `id`?