# dcast efficiently large datasets with multiple variables

Tags: r, reshape2, large-data, bigdata

I am trying to `dcast` a large dataset (millions of rows). I have one row for arrival time and origin, and another row for departure time and destination. There is an `id` to identify the unit in both cases. It looks similar to this:

```
id  time            movement    origin  dest
1   10/06/2011 15:54    ARR        15    15
1   10/06/2011 16:14    DEP        15    29
2   10/06/2011 17:59    ARR        73    73
2   10/06/2011 18:10    DEP        73    75
2   10/06/2011 21:10    ARR        75    75
2   10/06/2011 21:20    DEP        75    73
3   10/06/2011 17:14    ARR        17    17
3   10/06/2011 18:01    DEP        17    48
4   10/06/2011 17:14    ARR        49    49
4   10/06/2011 17:26    DEP        49    15
```

So, I would like to reallocate the pairs (`ARR`-`DEP`) and do this efficiently (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552810/optimizing-for-loop-in-big-data-frame)). As it is a very large dataset a `for loop` wouldn't work in this case. The ideal output would be

```
  index unitid origin   arr time    dest    dep time
    1    1     15   10/06/2011 14:33    29  10/06/2011 19:24
    2    2     73   10/06/2011 14:59    75  10/06/2011 17:23
    3    2     75   10/06/2011 21:10    73  10/06/2011 23:40
```

Data:

```
        df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(7L, 16L, 8L, 11L, 18L, 20L, 
10L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 15L, 19L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 17L
), .Label = c("10/06/2011 09:08", "10/06/2011 10:54", "10/06/2011 11:38", 
"10/06/2011 12:41", "10/06/2011 12:54", "10/06/2011 14:26", "10/06/2011 14:33", 
"10/06/2011 14:59", "10/06/2011 17:12", "10/06/2011 17:14", "10/06/2011 17:23", 
"10/06/2011 18:56", "10/06/2011 19:03", "10/06/2011 19:04", "10/06/2011 19:16", 
"10/06/2011 19:24", "10/06/2011 20:12", "10/06/2011 21:10", "10/06/2011 22:28", 
"10/06/2011 23:40"), class = "factor"), movement = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("ARR", "DEP", "ITZ"), class = "factor"), 
    origin = c(15L, 15L, 73L, 73L, 75L, 75L, 17L, 17L, 49L, 49L, 
    15L, 15L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 17L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L), dest = c(15L, 
    29L, 73L, 75L, 75L, 73L, 17L, 48L, 49L, 15L, 15L, 49L, 32L, 
    10L, 17L, 10L, 76L, 65L, 76L, 65L), id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
    8L)), .Names = c("time", "movement", "origin", "dest", "id"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe you could try `dcast.data.table` from the [1.9.8 branch of "data.table"](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/tree/1.9.8) (but expect that things might change since that's not the version on CRAN yet.

Comment: Hi @AnandaMahto, if I just want to pick the times, this code (by @akron) has worked before `dcast.data.table(setDT(df)[ ,c('.id', 'Seq'):= 
        list(c('arrival', 'departure'), gl(.N,2, .N))], id+Seq~.id, value.var='time')` however, if I want to add the origin and destination information, I don't really know how to pick it up. Bear in mind that it is a very large dataset (millions rows)

Comment: Could you please tell how many millions of rows you're dealing with?

Comment: 7-10 millions per file, with 100+ files to go through

Comment: @user3507584  I think this is solvable using similar method as docendo discimus showed using dplyr.  Have you tried the `dplyr/tidyr`?  It would be best to know the timings to see if that approach is indeed good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setorder(setDT(df), id, time)
df[, grp := FALSE][movement == "ARR", grp := TRUE]
df[, .(time[grp], time[!grp], origin[grp], dest[!grp]), by=id]
#    id                  V1                  V2 V3 V4
# 1:  1 10/06/2011 14:33:57 10/06/2011 19:24:16 15 29
# 2:  2 10/06/2011 14:59:14 10/06/2011 17:23:20 73 75
# 3:  2 10/06/2011 21:10:56 10/06/2011 23:40:29 75 73
# 4:  3 10/06/2011 17:14:44 10/06/2011 18:56:39 17 48
# 5:  4 10/06/2011 11:38:43 10/06/2011 14:26:43 49 15
# 6:  4 10/06/2011 19:16:55 10/06/2011 22:28:14 15 49
# 7:  5 10/06/2011 10:41:20 10/06/2011 12:54:26 10 17
# 8:  6 10/06/2011 09:08:05 10/06/2011 10:54:48 76 65
```

You can make this slightly faster if you add another column with value `!grp` and use that column instead of doing `!grp` on each group.

---

How this works:

- `setDT` converts data.frame to data.table by reference.
- `setorder` reorders a data.table by reference based on the columns (and the order) provided. Here, it reorders the rows of `df` in increasing order based on columns `id` and `time`.
- Then we use data.table's *sub-assign by reference* to add an extra column which holds the value `TRUE` when `movement == "ARR"` and `FALSE` when `movement == "DEP"`.

  Note: The factor levels in your `df$movement` column has an additional level called `ITZ` which doesn't seem to be in this sample data. Not sure how to handle that.
- Now all we have to do is pick 1,3,5, .. elements from `origin` and 2,4,6,... elements from `dest` (and similarly for `time`).

This works as long as `ARR` time is always before `DEP` time (which is very much a valid assumption).

---

Following OP's edit to the Q with inconsistencies in data:

```
na.omit(df[movement != "ITZ", .(time[grp], time[!grp], origin[grp], dest[!grp]), by=id])
```

Comment: Having 6.2 million rows, times for: `setorder(setDT(df), id, time)` 0.25 secs, `df[, grp := FALSE][movement == "ARR", grp := TRUE]` 0.53 secs, `df[, .(time[grp], time[!grp], origin[grp], dest[!grp]), by=id]` 6.52 secs. Total: 7.3 secs, so almost a million (900k) rows handled per second. Thanks so much @Arun

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is structured like in the example, i.e. there is one arrival and one departure time per id and origin, then you may be able to do this manually, just by re-ordering and subsetting your data (of course you have to be very very careful with this, and try to add as many checks as possible, like the one below, to catch errors)

```
dat <- df[order(df$id, df$origin, df$dest, df$movement), ]
dat.dep <- dat[dat$movement == "DEP", ]
dat.arr <- dat[dat$movement == "ARR", ]
stopifnot(nrow(dat.dep) == nrow(dat.arr) &
    dat.dep$origin == dat.arr$origin & 
    dat.dep$id == dat.arr$id)
result <- dat.dep[c("id", "origin", "dest")]
result$arr.time <- dat.arr$time
result$dep.time <- dat.dep$time
result 
#    id origin dest            arr.time            dep.time
# 2   1     15   29 10/06/2011 14:33:57 10/06/2011 19:24:16
# 4   2     73   75 10/06/2011 14:59:14 10/06/2011 17:23:20
# 6   2     75   73 10/06/2011 21:10:56 10/06/2011 23:40:29
# 8   3     17   48 10/06/2011 17:14:44 10/06/2011 18:56:39
# 12  4     15   49 10/06/2011 19:16:55 10/06/2011 22:28:14
# 10  4     49   15 10/06/2011 11:38:43 10/06/2011 14:26:43
# 14  5     10   17 10/06/2011 10:41:20 10/06/2011 12:54:26
# 16  6     76   65 10/06/2011 09:08:05 10/06/2011 10:54:48
```

Comment: @Arun I understand that. Isn't every data point uniquely determined by its id, origin and movement?

Comment: @Arun aaah now I see. So the issue was with my wording. I haven't assumed this in the solution though, I meant one arrival and one departure per id and origin.. thanks :)